# Can't access PHP object field with period in name

Tags: php, simplexml, stdclass

I've run into an issue with PHP and object key access.

I have a SimpleXMLElement that returns an array of 11 SimpleXMLElements as follows:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Power.AssetToAssetMapping] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [AssetToAssetMappingID] => 36063
                [Supplier_x0020_Asset_x0020_Type] => Powerstrip
                [..etc..]
```

When I try to isolate the array using braces, I only see the first record of the array. The other 10 are never output:

```
print_r( $xml->{'Power.AssetToAssetMapping'} );
```

When I use the whole object, I see all 11 records:

```
print_r( $xml );
```

Is there another way to access the first child of this object? I can foreach over each child of the object returned in $xml and get to each element just fine, but it seems like this is a bug in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `print_r`:

```
print_r( $xml->{'Power.AssetToAssetMapping'} );
```

SimpleXML will magically offer only the *first* matching element here. However, technically, using that value is actually a [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement) that will allow you to access either all (in form of a [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable)) or a specific one via (or similar to) [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) on a zero-based, integer index:

```
$xml->{'Power.AssetToAssetMapping'}[1];
```

That for example is the second `<Power.AssetToAssetMapping>` element under the root element.

```
foreach ($xml->{'Power.AssetToAssetMapping'} as $element) {
    // each element
    print_r($element);
}
```

That for example is an iteration over are all `<Power.AssetToAssetMapping>` elements under the root element, from first to last.

Take note that *this behavior is specific to `SimpleXMLElement`*. A simple `stdClass` does *not* behave in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert SimpleXMLElement Object to Array ;)

```
$xml = (array)$xml;
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary with SimpleXML? And does it even work?